# Scrapy Not Crawling in DFS Order

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, depth-first-search

Scrapy seems to be crawling pages in BFS order, though the docs say that by default the order should be DFS.

Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request


class DfsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dfs'
    allowed_domains = ['craigslist.org']
    start_urls = ['http://seattle.craigslist.org']

    def parse(self, response):
        print "URL FROM PARSE: ", response.url
        xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'community')]/div/div/ul/li/a/@href"
        for link in response.xpath(xpath):
            url = response.urljoin(link.extract())
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        print "URL FROM PARSE_DATA: ", response.url
        xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'content')]/p/span/span/a/@href"
        for link in response.xpath(xpath):
            url = response.urljoin(link.extract())
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_data_again)

    def parse_data_again(self, response):
        print "URL FROM PARSE_DATA_AGAIN: ", response.url
```

The output is a single "URL FROM PARSE: www.seattle.craigslist.org"
Followed by a bunch of "URL FROM PARSE_DATA: www.seattle.craigslist.org/search/..."

And then only later do I start seeing print statements from parse_data_again() method.

If Scrapy searches in DFS order, I should see:

"URL FROM PARSE: ..."

"URL FROM PARSE DATA: ..."

"URL FROM PARSE DATA_AGAIN: ..."

"URL FROM PARSE DATA_AGAIN: ..."

...

"URL FROM PARSE DATA_AGAIN: ..."

"URL FROM PARSE DATA: ..."

"URL FROM PARSE DATA_AGAIN: ..."

...

And so on. Now, I suspect that Scrapy uses some kind of threading, which is probably why requests are made and responses received in chaotic order. But multiple threads searching different parts of the tree is NOT DFS..

If this is the case, can I set Scrapy to only process one request at a time?

Or maybe I'm confused about something else. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think helpful in  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
```

Comment: I don't get how this got accepted. Your answer **increases the tendency towards BFS** instead of decreasing it. As the settings mention : DEPTH_PRIORITY

`Default: 0`

`a positive value will decrease the priority, i.e. higher depth requests will be processed later ; this is commonly used when doing breadth-first crawls (BFO)`
`a negative value will increase priority, i.e., higher depth requests will be processed sooner (DFO)`